# Blender does not scale or rotate in object mode?

Tags: transforms

When I try to scale or rotate an object in object mode it doesnt work however it does in edit mode .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stab in the dark, you might have 'Manipulate Center Points' selected, which prevents you from scaling and rotating an object in Object Mode.

[image]